# fit function expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, reshape, data-fitting

I am using Linear Regression to predict the 'Value' throughout the years, I have the following data, i imported from a csv file :
`**df.head()**` :

```
LOCATION    INDICATOR   SUBJECT MEASURE FREQUENCY   TIME    Value   Flag Codes
0   IRL LTINT   TOT PC_PA   M   1.167610e+18    4.04    NaN
1   IRL LTINT   TOT PC_PA   M   1.170288e+18    4.07    NaN
2   IRL LTINT   TOT PC_PA   M   1.172707e+18    3.97    NaN
3   IRL LTINT   TOT PC_PA   M   1.175386e+18    4.19    NaN
4   IRL LTINT   TOT PC_PA   M   1.177978e+18    4.32    NaN
```

The format of Time column was YYYY-DD-MM before i used the following

```
***df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype(float)***
```

In order to fit data i used the following code :

```
***X=df['TIME']
Y=df['Value']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
lm= LinearRegression()***
```

when executing the fit function ***lm.fit(X_train, Y_train)***, I got the following error :

```
        ***ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 lm.fit(X_train, Y_train)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1151, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1144     estimator._validate_params()
   1146 with config_context(
   1147     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1148         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1149     )
   1150 ):
-> 1151     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py:678, in LinearRegression.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    674 n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    676 accept_sparse = False if self.positive else ["csr", "csc", "coo"]
--> 678 X, y = self._validate_data(
    679     X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, y_numeric=True, multi_output=True
    680 )
    682 has_sw = sample_weight is not None
    683 if has_sw:
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:621, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    619         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    620     else:
--> 621         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    622     out = X, y
    624 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1147, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1142         estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)
   1143     raise ValueError(
   1144         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1145     )
-> 1147 X = check_array(
   1148     X,
   1149     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1150     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
   1151     dtype=dtype,
   1152     order=order,
   1153     copy=copy,
   1154     force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
   1155     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
   1156     allow_nd=allow_nd,
   1157     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
   1158     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
   1159     estimator=estimator,
   1160     input_name="X",
   1161 )
   1163 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
   1165 check_consistent_length(X, y)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:940, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    938     # If input is 1D raise error
    939     if array.ndim == 1:
--> 940         raise ValueError(
    941             "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    942             "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    943             "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
    944             "if it contains a single sample.".format(array)
    945         )
    947 if dtype_numeric and hasattr(array.dtype, "kind") and array.dtype.kind in "USV":
    948     raise ValueError(
    949         "dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings."
    950         "Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead."
    951     )
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1.3437792e+18 1.6198272e+18 1.3596768e+18 ... 1.3596768e+18 1.5805152e+18
 1.5751584e+18].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.***
```

Do you have any idea how can i resolve this error ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Side comment: your `TIME` values are quite high, I suggest transforming them (an affine map, like a min-max would be enough) to smaller values. For the sake of numerical stability.

Comment: Would you please suggest me a way to do it ?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `X=df['TIME']` to `X=df[['TIME']]`.

Double brackets gets a dataframe back (2d), single brackets gets a series back (1d)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me resolve the issue. Otherwise, would you please advise me, if you have an Idea, if this approch of having only two variables (value and Time), will help me predict interest rate, which is thé field 'value', throughout the year ? Or should I have other parameters ? I am kind of Lost in the part of data preparation

Comment: Predicting interest rates is a very difficult task--entire fields of research are devoted to it. Your approach of using the date-time as an independent variable in linear regression will help identify if there is a long-term trend. But time series methods are probably better suited if you don't have any other variables. I highly recommend this forecasting textbook: otexts.com/fpp3/, and asking additional modeling-related questions on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and guidance

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about scaling your time inputs:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TIME'])
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype(float)

X=df[['TIME']]
Y=df['Value']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)

scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit( X_train) # scaling on training only to better mimic generalization to new data
X_train, X_test = scaler.transform(X_train), scaler.transform(X_test)
```

using [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)